# What kinds of expressions have a self-similar open form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, closed-form, recursion, formal-power-series

A geometric series may be put in any of these 3 forms:

- Open form: $S = \sum^{i \in \mathbb{N_0}}\alpha^i$
- Self-similar form: $ S = 1 + \alpha S $
- Closed form: $ S = \frac{1}{1 - \alpha} $

If I take some other rational expression, say $\frac{1}{\alpha^2}$ or $\frac{\alpha + 1}{\alpha^2+1}$, would I be able to find a corresponding open form or self-similar form? What about other kinds of expressions, like polynomials and exponents?

**P.S.**   To clarify some:

An open form is not necessarily a sum. It may be a product, a continued fraction, or something else altogether. What matters is that there is not a fixed amount of operations.

A self-similar form is a recursive expression, that is, an expression defined in terms of itself. It may some time evaluate to a number; other times it will not evaluate at all, but remain formal.

Comment: I have no idea what tags to put.

Comment: Try going in reverse: If you have $S$ equal to any function linear in $S$ and rational in $\alpha$, then you can solve for $S$ as a rational function of $\alpha$. And using partial fraction decomposition, the rational function can be written as a sum of infinite sums like $1/\alpha^n=\sum_k(1-\alpha^n)^k$.

Comment: @mr_e_man This is by far above my head. Would it be too much to ask you to expound in an answer?

Comment: If $S=p(\alpha)+q(\alpha)S$ where $p$ and $q$ are rational functions, then $S=p(\alpha)/(1-q(\alpha))$ which is also rational. And see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partial-fractions?tab=Frequent

Comment: But what exactly do you mean by self-similar?

Comment: @mr_e_man I specifically was not being exact. One possible definition is $\exists f S = f(S)$, another is that there is some syntactic transformation that folds an open form like this, yet another is that the series may be given by a recursive function. I am at the very first steps of this road.

Comment: You can roll back my edits if you disagree with them

Comment: I would not take anything personally if you disagreed with my edits. After all, you're the one who knows what the subject of your question is.

Comment: If $S=f(S)$ for some function $f$, then there's another function $g(S)=f(S)-S$ such that $g(S)=0$. So that definition of self-similarity is equivalent to $S$ being a root of some (polynomial?) function.

Comment: @mr_e_man This is a sharp observation! I have not looked at it from this point of view.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the sort of thing you would be looking for.

Suppose we define the sequence $(q_n)_{n\in\Bbb N_0}$ by the recurrence
$$q_{n+2}=aq_{n+1}+bq_n\qquad n\ge0,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are non-zero constants. Assume the base cases $q_0,q_1$ are given. Say we define the function $$q(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}q_nx^n.$$
Then we can multiply both sides of our recurrence by $x^{n+2}$ and sum over $n\in\Bbb N_0$:
$$\sum_{n\ge0}q_{n+2}x^{n+2}=a\sum_{n\ge0}q_{n+1}x^{n+2}+b\sum_{n\ge0}q_n x^{n+2}.$$
The sum on the left is 
$$\sum_{n\ge0}q_{n+2}x^{n+2}=\sum_{n\ge2}q_nx^n=-q_0-q_1x+\sum_{n\ge0}q_nx^n=q(x)-q_1x-q_0.$$
The next sum is 
$$\sum_{n\ge0}q_{n+1}x^{n+2}=x\sum_{n\ge0}q_{n+1}x^{n+1}=x(q(x)-q_0).$$
And the last sum is $$\sum_{n\ge0}q_nx^{n+2}=x^2\sum_{n\ge0}q_nx^n=x^2 q(x).$$
Finally,
$$q(x)-q_1x-q_0=axq(x)-axq_0+bx^2q(x),$$
which is 
$$q(x)=\frac{(q_1-aq_0)x+q_0}{1-ax-bx^2}.$$

In a similar fashion, if the sequence $(q_n)$ is instead defined by 
$$q_{n+k}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\alpha_j q_{n+j}$$
for constants $\alpha_j$ and $k$, then we can show that 
$$q(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}q_nx^n=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(q_jx^j-\alpha_j\sum_{r=0}^{j-1}q_rx^{k+r-j}\right)}{1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\alpha_j x^{k-j}}.$$

Comment: I do not know either. I am going to chew on it for a while.

Comment: I see, so what you are showing is that a formal power series inductively defined via a collection of linear equations _(maybe with some additional restrictions)_ can be folded to a closed form of a ratio of two polynomials. Is that right?

Comment: exactly. I thought this might fit your definition of 'self-similar' because for each $q(x)$, there is a function $f(x,y)$ which satisfies $$q(x)=f(x,q(x))$$

Comment: You maybe meant to say $$ q_{n + k} = \sum_{j = 0}^{k - 1}\alpha_{j} q_{n + j} $$? _(Notice that $n$.)_

Comment: yes. thank for catching that